# Why is DRF's router selectively not redirecting to a trailing slash?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

### **Desired behavior**

For router endpoints to append a trailing slash if one is not provided.

E.g. `/api/customers` would redirect to `/api/customers/`

### **Actual behavior**

A 404 is returned if a trailing slash isn't applied to the endpoint.

E.g. `/api/customers` return a `404` response

[Image of 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DvP8.png)

### **Additional context**

- `APPEND_SLASH` is set to `True`
- `CommonMiddleware` is set
- The trailing slash works on non-DRF endpoints. E.g. `/admin` redirects to `/admin/`
- The trailing slash works on one set of ViewSet endpoints. The `user` ViewSet works. E.g. `/users` redirects to `/users/`
- The `user` app is the last app in the project alphabetically.
- None of the other ViewSets registered redirect to the trailing slash.

### **Code**

`project_name/urls.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers

from user.views import UserViewSet, LoginView, logout_view
from customer.views import CustomerViewSet
from intake.views import IntakeViewSet
from extraction.views import ExtractionViewSet


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='users')
router.register(r'customers', CustomerViewSet, basename='customers')
router.register(r'intakes', IntakeViewSet, basename='intakes')
router.register(r'extractions', ExtractionViewSet, basename='extractions')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/login/', LoginView.as_view()),
    path('api/logout/', logout_view),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    # Add dev static files
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    # Add debug toolbar patterns
    urlpatterns.append(path('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls')))
```

`user/views.py`

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

`customer/views.py`

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def addresses(self, request, pk=None):
        customer = self.get_object()
        queryset = Address.objects.filter(customer=customer)
        serializer = AddressSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    @addresses.mapping.post
    def add_address(self, request, pk=None):
        customer = self.get_object()
        serializer = AddressSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(customer=customer)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def contacts(self, request, pk=None):
        customer = self.get_object()
        queryset = Contact.objects.filter(customer=customer)
        serializer = ContactSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @contacts.mapping.post
    def add_contact(self, request, pk=None):
        customer = self.get_object()
        serializer = ContactSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(customer=customer)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

`intake/views.py`

```
class IntakeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Intake.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IntakeSerializer
```

### **TLDR**

Only one set of endpoints registered to DRF's router redirects when a trailing slash isn't added.

Comment: which endpoint redirects and which doesn't when a trailing slash is / is not added?

Comment: Did you do any tinkering on the ViewSets? I'd be curious to see the `CustomerViewSet` as an example.

Comment: @Tarquinius I've added the viewset code to the post. As you can see, there is a difference between the `UserViewSet` with some of the other apps (`CustomerViewSet`), but the same with others (`IntakeViewSet`).

Comment: @MuhammadWaqarAnwar In the post under "Additional context" I outline which endpoints redirect and which do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The culprit was in `urls.py`:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    # Add dev static files
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    # Add debug toolbar patterns
    urlpatterns.append(path('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls')))
```

The `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` variables were not set in the settings. This created a catch all url pattern that caught any endpoint that didn't include a trailing slash.

**Everything works after setting these variables**.